# How to check if embed image has a valid/working link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

What I'm trying to do is to set the embed's image to the value of `args[0]` and if it does not work, then set the embed's image to a default, working link.

I have this code:

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
exampleEmbed.addField('Its a title!', 'Its a value!');
try {
    exampleEmbed.setImage(args[0]);
}
catch (error) { 
    exampleEmbed.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');
};
message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

The problem is, when args[0] is not a working url (for eg. something like 'https://' or 'https://.com') the `try` block will still be executed succesfully and the `catch` block **won't be executed**.
However, because of the unvalid link, when when I want to send my embed I get this error message:

`(node:19196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embed.image.url: Not a well formed URL.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the `args[0]` content with a regex matcher, and if it doesn't match an URI pattern you could throw an error.

```js
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
exampleEmbed.addField('Its a title!', 'Its a value!');
try {

    if (!(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g).test(args[0])) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid URL`);
    }
    exampleEmbed.setImage(args[0]);
}
catch (error) { 
    exampleEmbed.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');
};
message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the cleanest way, but sure it works and solves my problem with a link like [https://sometexthere/](https://sometexthere/), so thank youi :)

Answer (score 1):

Validate the `args[0]` using [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_url) class:

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
exampleEmbed.addField('Its a title!', 'Its a value!');

let url = validateURL(args[0]);

if (url) {
  exampleEmbed.setImage(url);
} else {
  exampleEmbed.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');
}

message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);


function validateURL(url) {
  try {
    return (new URL(url)).toString();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, when `args[0]` is only something like [https://sometexthere](https://sometexthere), the program will still say it's a valid url, however the embed says it is not and the embed won't be sent to the channel.